# Why MySQL connections remain in CLEANED UP state for a very long time in nodejs application using sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have developed a nodejs application which uses sequelize ORM with mysql.Below is my sequelize configuration file.

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const moment = require('moment');
const sequelize = new Sequelize("test", "root", "", {
  host:
    "127.0.0.1",
  port: 3309,
  dialect: "mysql",
  dialectOptions: {
    connectTimeout: 30000
  },
 pool: {
    max: 100,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 60000,
    idle: 10000,
    evict: 600000, // Time interval to check for idle connections to evict in milliseconds (optional)
    maxIdleTime: 30000,
  },
  logging: (query, timing) => {
    const timestamp = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    console.log(`[${timestamp}] SQL Query: ${query} Elapsed Time: ${timing} ms`);
  },
   benchmark: true,
});

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connection has been established successfully.");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Unable to connect to the database:", err);
  });

module.exports = sequelize;
```

I am using both promises and Async/Await in the application.
Below is a sample Async/await trasnactions.

```
 try {
  (async () => {
    const t = await sequelize.transaction();
    try {
      const updateUser = await User.update(
        {
          update_column: "s",
        },
        {
          where: {
            username: "sadisha",
          },
          transaction: t,
        },
      );
      //some condition
      if (some_condition) {
        throw new Error("User account update failed");
      }
      await t.commit();
      return {
        status: true,
      };
    } catch (Exception) {
      console.log(Exception);
      await t.rollback();
      return {
        status: false,
      };
    }
  })()
    .then((responseFromAsync) => {
      if (responseFromAsync.status) {
        //do something
      } else {
        //do something
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
} catch (Exception) {
  console.log(Exception);
}
```

**I have observed that nodejs is holding on to db connections which are in CLEANED UP state for very long time(After seeing show processlist).Sometimes it is close 8 hours.This normally occurs in the peek hours of requests.When the number of requests per second is low,this is not ocuring.When nodejs application is restarted ,those db connections are gets released.**
Up to now I have tried below things.

1. Indexing mysql database
2. Optimizing queries
3. Manipulating sequlize configuration file( as in above)

What is causing this behaviour?

Comment: Try to check all places where you use transactions and make sure there is no missing ` await t.rollback();` or just missing `await` before it in catch clause or any place where you can dangle transaction.

Comment: @l2ysho I haven't found any of those

Comment: This looks like complex problem, in most of cases are these problems caused by incorrect usage of transactions, (transaction should be created right before usage, commited/rollbacked as soon as posible, used only in queries where are really needed...). Can't say this is your case, just trying to find solution for symptoms and this fits (as you said, it happends in the peek hours). Try use autocannon to find problematic api routes